# ras (dial-up) has no Internet after VPN setup

Tags: vpn

What's wrong with my configurations? RAS Interface han no Internet. I had given static IP pool to VPN users, 192.168.1.2 - 192.168.1.254. I am really stuck!

Screenshot of my config:

[image]